# Pointer to a structure that has not been declared

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [undefined C struct forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621356/undefined-c-struct-forward-declaration)

How is it possible to declare a pointer to structure even when I do not declare a structure?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    struct s{
     struct p *ptr;
   }; 
}
```

Why does the above compile successfully?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326205/what-is-forward-reference-in-c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible because the compiler doesn't need to know anything about the structure if it only deals with a pointer to it.

This is a commonly used technique and is usually called an “opaque pointer”.

Comment: can you please link me to a detailed explanation ?

Comment: @Parminder There's a section called "Self-referential Structures" in *The C Programming Language*.

Comment: Effectively, the `struct p` line _is_ a declaration.

Comment: @dreamlax: I think good explanation by you... But a new thing I learnt today is Opaque Pointer... Anyhow Thanks

Comment: @cnicutar: I think the above code is not a self referential structure..

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak True but that section explains why this is possible (forward declaration stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Look into the below link

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/100298-opaque-pointer.html