# forward reference with respect to pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is forward reference in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326205/what-is-forward-reference-in-c)

I read this question somewhere

```
"What is forward reference with respect to pointers in C, and what are its advantages"
```

The accepted answer mentioned in here : [What is forward reference in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326205/what-is-forward-reference-in-c)
doesn't give a proper explanation?
Can anyone explain what exactly it means? and does it have any advantages?

Comment: I guess I mentioned that in question.. please care enough to read the question before downvoting

Answer (score 2):

Forward Referencing wrt Pointers is the term we use, when

**A pointer is declared and compiler reserves the memory for the pointer but the DataItem is not defined to which the pointer points to.**

From the previous answers::

```
struct MyStruct *ptr; // this is a forward reference cuz pointer ptr is declared
                      // but the structure it points to is itself not defined till now.

struct MyStruct // Now the structure is declared
{
       // some data members
};
```

Advantages:: [Advantages](http://www.visualcpp.org/?p=82)

Comment: In this 
struct MyStruct;
struct MyStruct *ptr;
struct MyStruct var;  // ILLEGAL
why is var illegal?

Comment: See the point is, compiler needs to know the size of "struct MyStruct" to reserve memory for "var" but "ptr" is a "pointer" which will only store the address, thus to reserve memory of "ptr", compiler already knows the amount of memory to allocate.